# Convert graph-based machine IR into serialised machine code?

Tags: compiler-construction, backend

I assume compiler backends will have one step to convert a graph-based machine code IR into serialised machine code before the assembler emits the code.

But what is this step called? 
I think this step can be trivial, but it seems necessary that, for the sake of performance,  in this step, to rearrange MC basic blocks to let some branches fall-through instead of jumping around. But I found little information on this.

I found the term 'trace scheduling' and 'branch folding'. They seem to be kind of related.

Comment: What kind of "graph machine IR"? A selection DAG, or something of a lower level?

Comment: @SK-logic if you are referring to something like LLVM's selection DAG, no, what I meant was the machine code representation generated from instruction selection (from selection DAG). I assume it is still a graph-based representation, and the backend needs to somehow serialise it. Am I wrong?

Comment: in LLVM selection DAG carries a mixture of the machine instructions and virtual instructions throughout a number of passes. Then a flat sequence is scheduled and emitted out of this DAG. Scheduling is not trivial, see an overview here: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/11/24/life-of-an-instruction-in-llvm/

Answer (score 2):

The general term is *instruction scheduling*. LLVM's [back-end documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#the-high-level-design-of-the-code-generator) calls the linearization step "scheduling and formation".

> The scheduling phase takes the DAG of target instructions from the selection phase and assigns an order. The scheduler can pick an order depending on various constraints of the machines (i.e. order for minimal register pressure or try to cover instruction latencies). Once an order is established, the DAG is converted to a list of MachineInstrs and the SelectionDAG is destroyed.
>
> Note that this phase is logically separate from the instruction selection phase, but is tied to it closely in the code because it operates on SelectionDAGs.

As the documentation says, the order chosen is usually for some aspect of performance.  In addition to register pressure and instruction latency, instructions of different types (e.g., int and float math) may be interleaved to keep all the processor's functional units utilized, or instructions/blocks may be reordered to remove branches or allow use of more compact "short jump" instructions when optimizing for code size.  Unfortunately for compiler writers (and users), instruction selection, instruction scheduling, and register allocation interact in complex ways, so generating "optimal" code isn't feasible for even small pieces of code.